# Why does BitAnd::bitand() not allow references?

Tags: rust, reference, overriding, bitwise-operators, traits

This code:

```
impl<I> BitAnd for BitSparseArray<I> where I: PrimInt + Unsigned + std::fmt::Debug {
    type Output = Self;

    fn bitand(&self, rhs: &Self) -> Self::Output {
        assert_eq!(self.numbits, rhs.numbits);
        ...
    }
}
```

fails to compile with:

```
error[E0053]: method `bitand` has an incompatible type for trait
  --> src/lib.rs:44:5
   |
44 |     fn bitand(&self, rhs: &Self) -> Self::Output {
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `BitSparseArray`, found reference
   |
   = note: expected fn pointer `fn(BitSparseArray<I>, BitSparseArray<I>) -> BitSparseArray<_>`
              found fn pointer `fn(&BitSparseArray<I>, &BitSparseArray<I>) -> BitSparseArray<_>`
```

And a move operation would result without the reference, which means the user of this will lose the source structures to a move.

Why would there not be an option to do references here as well? Of course, I could use explicit functions to do what I want, but that would not be as cool of an approach!

Comment: When implementing trait methods, they have to have the exact same declaration as in the trait. The `BitAnd` trait expects a method that takes ownership of the operands. However, it can still be implemented for reference types. I.e, `impl BitAnd for &'_ BitSparseArray` works.

Comment: https://gitlab.com/snippets/1981909

The above is the snippet of other changes I had to do to make this work. Thanks.